# HTML parser import issues

Tags: python, web-crawler, html-parser

So I'm trying to make a web crawler in python using HTMLParser and urllib3 in python. Currently I have two different import problems the first being

```
import html.parser
import urllib

urlText = []

#Define HTML Parser
class parseText(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

def handle_data(self, data):
    if data != '\n':
        urlText.append(data)


#Create instance of HTML parser
lParser = parseText()

thisurl = "http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~gawron/index.html"
#Feed HTML file into parser
lParser.feed(urllib.urlopen(thisurl).read())
lParser.close()
for item in urlText:
    print (item)
```

and with this code it returns an error in the visual studio error box

```
name 'HTMLParser' is not defined
```

and the second option is the exact same but with import HTMLParser instead of html.parser

```
import HTMLParser
import urllib

urlText = []

#Define HTML Parser
class parseText(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

def handle_data(self, data):
    if data != '\n':
        urlText.append(data)


#Create instance of HTML parser
lParser = parseText()

thisurl = "http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~gawron/index.html"
#Feed HTML file into parser
lParser.feed(urllib.urlopen(thisurl).read())
lParser.close()
for item in urlText:
    print (item)
```

which returns the error

```
No module named 'markupbase'
```

I'm losing my mind with the packages. Does anyone know a fix or see a problem.
Ps. I'm running this in Visual studio 2016 and am in Python 3.5

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in your second sample. Please show a full traceback. Also fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also following the same tutorial that you are following to learn web crawling. I also got those issues yesterday when I run that code. After a few google search I resolved those. I am new to python and web crawling, so correct me if I say something wrong.

If you are using python 3.5 you should import [`HTMLParser from html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)
and [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request). 
At line 7 you have to inherit just HTMLParser instead of HTMLParser.HTMLParser.
At this point your code should be look like this

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

urlText = []

#Define HTML Parser
class parseText(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data != '\n':
            urlText.append(data)


#Create instance of HTML parser
lParser = parseText()

thisurl = "http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~gawron/index.html"
#Feed HTML file into parsers
lParser.feed(urllib.request.urlopen(thisurl).read())
lParser.close()
for item in urlText:
    print (item)
```

Now if you run this code you will this error

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

that's because `HTMLParser.feed()` only takes string and `urllib.request.urlopen().read()` generates raw data as bytes. So we are going to decode this raw data as utf8. At line 19 we add `.decode('utf8')`after `read()`.
The final code will be look like

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

urlText = []

#Define HTML Parser
class parseText(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data != '\n':
            urlText.append(data)


#Create instance of HTML parser
lParser = parseText()

thisurl = "http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~gawron/index.html"
#Feed HTML file into parsers
lParser.feed(urllib.request.urlopen(thisurl).read().decode('utf8'))
lParser.close()
for item in urlText:
    print (item)
```

Converting bytes to sting also works with this at line 19

```
lParser.feed(str(urllib.request.urlopen(thisurl).read()))
```

but if i use this handle_data won't recognize any whitespace such as '\n'.
So the code works fine without removing any '\n'.

Comment: Thank you so very much. This helped a ton and was the perfect answer.

Comment: Are you still following that tutorial?